# Setting the Context Window Screen Layout Explicitly in BPY

Tags: python

In 2.7 you could set the active screen layout with, e. g. for "UV Editing":

```
bpy.context.window.screen=bpy.data.screens['UV Editing']
```

This no longer seems to have any effect in 2.81.

Some new means to make it kick in?

Incidentally, does 2.8+ support a shortcut to switch it explicity? I had defined my own operator in a startup script just to do so, which used the line above.

Answer (score 3):

The current workspace can be changed to the *UV Editing* workspace through:

```
bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['UV Editing']
```

This assumes that a workspace named *UV Editing* exists. In order to check for the case where it doesn't exist, use `bpy.data.workspaces.get('UV Editing')` instead and verify that the returned value is not `None`.

---

The current area type can be changed through [`bpy.context.area.type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type). In order to change to the UV editor you can use:

```
area = bpy.context.area
area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
area.ui_type = 'UV'
```

Although it's not documented in the manual you can also just assign the `ui_type` and it will automatically change the `type` as well.

```
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'UV'
```

If you want to change a different area than the current one, you can iterate through `bpy.context.screen.areas`.

Comment: That will change just the one area, i. e. window, within the screen layout you're in. What we want is to change bpy.context.screen entirely, to a different pre-set layout. as per the tabs at the top of the screen.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. So you want to change to the *UV Editing* workspace? The concepts and API changed a little from 2.79.